# How do I use a subquery to show a column that has never been assigned to a different table?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I'm trying to Write a SELECT statement that returns the category_name column from the Categories table and returns one row for each category that has never been assigned to a product in the Products table. there are four categories in the categories table and
only three have been used in the products table. How do i make it show the one that
hasn't been used?
this is the code I've been trying, but it returns an empty result set.

```
select category_name
from categories c natural join products p
where not exists (
select category_name, category_id 
from categories c natural join products p);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query returns `NULL` because the subquery returns at least one row.  Hence something exists.  Juergen's answer shows how to do what you want with a `left join`.  Here is how you solve the problem using `not exists`:

```
select c.category_name
from categories c
where not exists (select 1 from products p where p.category_id = c.category_id);
```

Comment: This seems so simple that I'm almost ashamed I didn't think of it. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use a `left join`. I don't know your relation between those 2 tables but I assumed it is `category.id` and `product.category_id`

```
select c.category_name
from categories c 
left join products p on c.id = p.category_id
where p.category_id is null
```